# Unable to use a string as a parameter on an another class

Tags: c++

I created a simple function in my cpp that prints out a text. Here's the code:

```
#include "Sally.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Sally::Sally()
{

}

void Sally::tell(string t){

    cout << t << endl;

}
```

and here's how I prototype it on my .h file:

```
#ifndef SALLY_H
#define SALLY_H
class Sally
{
    public:

        Sally();
        void tell(string t);
    protected:

    private:
};

#endif // SALLY_H
```

Here are the errors:

```
Sally.h|8|error: 'string' has not been declared|
Sally::tell(std::__cxx11::string)' does not match any in class 'Sally'|
Sally.h|8|error: candidate is: void Sally::tell(int)|
```

It gives me an error whenever I build it. It doesn't have any problems at all if I'm using int as a parameter. So the problem is that I wish to use a string as a parameter.

Comment: Have you included <string> ?

Comment: It would help if we could see Sally.h

Comment: You need to include string library I think `#include <string>`

Comment: Show us the error message.

Comment: i did sir. I just tried it now and it's still not working

Comment: I just included the #include <string> and it's still now working.

Comment: here are the errors:

Comment: Please post a [mcve], and also the full error message,

Comment: Don't post the error etc. in comments, [edit] your question to put it in it.

Comment: I've edited the post. Im sorry didnt know that it contains both cpp. It now has the .h file

Comment: now you just need to show us the compilation error. As you can see [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/JCEYfUvEiErCFsMm) code has no issues? So apart from yours being across multiple files, what is different?

Comment: I've included the error logs sir.

Comment: I already did it sir and still not working

Comment: You are probably only `using namespace std` in one of your files, but writing `string` in both. Best practice is to never use `using namespace std` and just type out `std::string`, but you can also include `using namespace std` in both files.

Comment: in the header use the full name `std::string`. Don't get in the habit of `using namespace std;` in header files.

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you guys for helping me. I'm new to c++. I'm so sorry. Haha

Comment: Do I have to put std::string on all files?

Comment: That's what I would recommend. `using namespace std;` pulls all symbols of `namespace std` into global namespace. This might produce surprising effects (and hard-to-track errors) as it might change where which symbol is found and which other symbols are eclipsed by this. Have a look at this Q/A to learn more: [SO: Why is “using namespace std” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/7478597).

Comment: I would like to see a file with main() function

Answer (score 1):

do some changes to your .h file:

```
#include <string>
```

and add `std::` in front of your string:

```
void tell(std::string t);
```